# Self-signed certificate for facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

I made a simple app for a Facebook page, but after making it public I am facing the problem below.
Can you please let me know what is there to be done? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to buy a valid SSL certificate on a trusted authority like http://www.rapidssl.com/. Once installed for your domain alexis.cimru.ro, you won't have this warning anymore.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass/redirect it? or free hosting on a trusted authority ?

Comment: No you can't bypass it and Facebook force you to have a SSL to allow then to provide a secure connexion on all their properties. It may exist a host offering a folder or sub-domain of a main site protected by SSL, but I don't know one.